# How can i fetch all data present in Map<String,Map<String,String>> data structure?

Tags: java, dictionary

i want to retrieve all data that are present in my data structure, which is of type Map of Maps.The data structure is mentioned below.

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> hourlyMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

i need all the data that are stored in the map irrespective of key.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of Map?

Comment: for Map<String,String> i tried but unable to implement for above data structure.

Comment: keySet() will give you keys of outer map.. iterate over the values and for each value , get keySet and values..

Comment: you have to iterate through your structure recursively and collect all the `value`'s

Comment: Why would you need recursion for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> hourlyMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    for(Map<String,String> i:hourlyMap.values()){
        // now i is a Map<String,String>
        for(String str:i.values()){
            // now str is a value of map i
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it worked .. if i want to show the value of each key in outer map with the associated key value pair in inner map .Then what should be the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Set<String> allData = new HashSet<>();     // will contain all the values
for(Map<String, String> map : hourlyMap.values()) {
    allData.addAll(map.values());
}
```

Comment: +1, because it's the most concise variant. However, it should be `.values()` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (String outerKey: hourlyMap.keySet()) {
        // outerKey holds the Key of the outer map
        // the value will be the inner map - hourlyMap.get(outerKey)

        System.out.println("Outer key: " + outerKey);
        for (String innerKey: hourlyMap.get(outerKey).keySet()) {

            // innerKey holds the Key of the inner map
            System.out.println("Inner key: " + innerKey);

            System.out.println("Inner value:" + hourlyMap.get(outerKey).get(innerKey));
        }

    }
```